# MongoDB: is it possible to avoid using automatic _id field?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I have a unique ID field of type `int` in my documents. I'm doing `ensureIndex` on this field, but my documents still contain `_id`. Can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-The%5CidField) ...

> If a user tries to insert a document without providing an _id field,
>   the database will automatically generate an *object id* and store it
>   the _id field.

However, you can assign your own value to **_id** ...

> The _id value may be of any type, other than arrays, so long as it is
>   a unique.

The better question is why would you create your own unique ID, build an index on it and remove the very useful ObjectID **_id** that is auto indexed?

All the official drivers use ObjectID and it has a lot of really good aspects to it:

- It has a timestamp built in (so you don't need to store a date field
  in your document, and you can use it to order by date.)
- It is a "global, uniformly increasing sequence number" --- i.e.
  it'll still be unique across servers if you need to shard your data,
  etc.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to MongoDB and I've missed the part of the documentation you've quoted. And thanks for explaining the benefits of using ObjectID. Still, I want to use my ID becuase it's a hash (and I need to store it in my document anyway), and it's smaller than ObjectID.

Comment: Happy to help, obviously its about what is best for your application but I've found the ObjectID to be very helpful in a number of situations I wouldn't have thought about when I first started. Have fun, http://learnmongo.com might be helpful for you too!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get rid of it, [it is there by design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs), but you can map your unique identifier `int` to the `_id` itself when inserting documents.

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would to store your hash into the _id field.

Thus, the database won't create automatically the _id field because it will already exist and you will save the space of an unused index.

Just set the _id field as any other with the value you want (your hash for instance). But be careful, it needs to be unique !

To ensure unicity you should either make it unique or put a subdocument in the _id field : 
{ _id : { h : [yourHash], u : [a unique identifier]} , ...}

Comment: That's exactly what I did, killing two birds with one shot: my documents don't contain huge ObjectID, and I don't need to call `ensureIndex` after every insert - I got a significant speedup (I would never think `ensureIndex` is so slow).

Comment: @Violet Giraffe: There's no need to call `ensureIndex` after every insert - it only needs to be called once in the lifetime of the database, just like with MySQL. Also, `ObjectID` is not really a 'huge' field. Still, I agree that using a hash makes sense. In the discussion of hash vs. object id vs. guid, make sure you understand the long-term implications of coherency and potential shard keys.